# Is "to down" grammatical in this little text?

Tags: grammaticality

Is this headline:

> Kansas, With a Record Comeback, Snatches N.C.A.A. Title Over North Carolina

> The Jayhawks rallied from a 16-point deficit to down the Tar Heels in a spirited — and physical — men’s basketball tournament final."

What is meant by "to down the the Tar Heels"?

Answer (score 3):

According to [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/down), one meaning of "down" as a verb is "to defeat, especially in sports". This article is talking about the results of a basketball game, so "the Jayhawks rallied ... **to down** the Tar Heels" means that the Jayhawks (team from Kansas) defeated the Tar Heels (team from North Carolina) in this basketball game.

Answer (score 2):

to down a team means to beat them.

Sports language can very quirky.

And this is just a headline trying to be one.

Not the best writing, I'd say.